# Messages shown in the developer console in spite of "error" filtered

Tags: javascript, chromium

I have a lot of "action" entries in my log. When I switch to "Errors only", these still appear (though each entry is empty - presumably *those* are not error messages).

How can I get rid of these?

[image: Actions]

Comment: These are not "log" messages, these are group statements which could contain log, information, warning or error messages; the inside of these groups however will be filtered.

Comment: What version of Chrome?

Comment: @SalmanA interesting, then how would I go about getting rid of these "group messages"?

Comment: @j08691: not chrome, chromium. latest version.

Comment: @ChristianNeverdal No idea. May be replace `console.group` and `console.groupCollapsed` functions with your own implementation. I created a stack snippet to show what is going on (you need enough rep to see deleted answers).

Comment: How come you made a deleted answer? (What about a gist or pastebin?) - I do not have enough reputation to view deleted answers unfortunately.

Comment: @SalmanA: your suggestion worked, feel free to make an answer and receive upvote, accepted answer, and bounty. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The downward pointing triangles indicate that these messages are generated by [`console.group`](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/console-reference#group) function which is not affected by the filter. The functions that are affected by the filter are [`console.log`](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/console-reference#log), [`console.info`](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/console-reference#consoleinfoobject_object), [`console.warn`](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/console-reference#warn) and [`console.error`](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/console-reference#error).

If you run the following code sample with filters you will notice that the *content* inside groups is affected by the filters but the group itself is not:

```js
console.clear();
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  console.group("Group %d", i);
  for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
    var fn = ["log", "info", "warn", "error", "debug"];
    var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * fn.length);
    console[fn[r]]("%s message", fn[r]);
  }
  console.groupEnd();
}
```

The solution is to overwrite the `console.group` and `console.groupCollapsed` function <del>which honors the filters</del> with your own implementation (e.g. `console.group = console.groupCollapsed = function() {};`).